# Microsoft speech-to-text restful api return “Empty reply from server”

Tags: speech-to-text

[the question link is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/693374/speech-to-text-restful-api-return-empty-reply-from.html)

Currently I am using speech-to-text restful api ，the ogg container format is written by myself ，this ogg file can be played directly ,but i don't know why the microsoft engine return “Empty reply from server” , the retCode is 100 .

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://japaneast.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US' --header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxx' --header 'Content-Type: audio/ogg; codecs=opus' --data-binary @'output.ogg'
```

you can download the file from the following link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18bn2_lxe6VO0AP7t0Bcbp4z3uuKAriob/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LMZh1_3PAEm8vNYkHcB6jxUge1M1wXlz/view?usp=sharing

I can use MediaInfo tools to view my ogg file information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSXDz.png)

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Why can't my ogg file get a response ？How can i get correct reply?

Comment: Please, follow the guidelines when making a question. It's not clear, it doesn't even have a question mark. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have found the reason 
. 
According to rfc7845,
   In ogg container ,   All fields in the ID headers are REQUIRED, except for 'channel
   mapping table', which MUST be omitted when the channel mapping family
   is 0, but is REQUIRED otherwise.

In my oggfile, erros due to automatic memory alignment, when Mapping Family equal 0 , still have  Channel Mapping Table Filed. 

PS:The same file, I can get the translation result through google engine.